# why autoincrement primary key column not autoincrementing in sqlite3

Tags: perl, sqlite

I have an sqlite3 db for an address book, and I created the address table with

```
 my $dbcreate = qq(CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS address
   (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT,
   LASTNAME TEXT    NOT NULL,
   FIRSTNAME    TEXT    NOT NULL,
   COMPANY  TEXT,
   STREET   TEXT,
   CITY     TEXT,
   STATE    TEXT,
   COUNTRY  TEXT,
   ZIPCODE  TEXT,
   MOBILE   TEXT,
   OTHERPHONE   TEXT,
   FAX          TEXT,
   EMAIL    TEXT,
   EMAIL2   TEXT,
   WEBSITE      TEXT,
   WEBSITE2     TEXT,
   DOB      DATE,
   NOTES    TEXT,
   TAGS         TEXT););
```

So the first column SHOULD, as I understand it, be an autoincrementing primary ID, only, it's not autoincrementing. My understanding from reading sqlite tutorials is that I should only have to enter the other 18 values, and that column should autoincrement, but if I insert 18 values, I'm told I'm missing one.
I've only been able to insert rows if I manually set the ROWID.
What gives?

Here's how I'm adding rows (unsuccessfully)

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl -w

# script to enter a new addressbook entry

use DBI;
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Please enter a DB username? \n";
my $userid=<STDIN>;
chomp($userid);

print "Please enter a DB password? \n";
my $password=<STDIN>;
chomp($password);

my $driver   = "SQLite";
my $database = "myaddress.db";
my $dsn = "DBI:$driver:dbname=$database";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $userid, $password, { RaiseError => 1 })
                      or die $DBI::errstr;
print "Successfull DB connection\n";

print "Creating new address book entry\n";
my $arval = 0;
my @dbits = ('LASTNAME','FIRSTNAME','COMPANY','STREET','CITY','STATE','COUNTRY','ZIPCODE','MOBILE','OTHERPHONE','FAX','EMAIL','EMAIL2','WEBSITE','WEBSITE2','DOB','NOTES','TAGS');
# print "@dbits";
# for $b (0 .. 17) {
    # print "\'$dbits[$b]\', ";
# }
print "-----\n";
my @nubits = ();
foreach my $databit(@dbits) {
    print "Enter $databit: \n";
    my $nubit = <STDIN>;
    chomp($nubit);
    print "$databit = $nubit\n\n";
    push(@nubits,$nubit);
    print "$databit = $nubits[$arval]\n";
    my $arval = (++$arval);
    print "$arval\n";
}

# print "new entry will be:\n";
# for $b (0 .. 17) {
    # print "$nubits[$b] | ";
# }

my $entry = qq(INSERT INTO address VALUES('$nubits[0]','$nubits[1]','$nubits[2]','$nubits[3]','$nubits[4]','$nubits[5]','$nubits[6]','$nubits[7]','$nubits[8]','$nubits[9]','$nubits[10]','$nubits[11]','$nubits[12]','$nubits[13]','$nubits[14]','$nubits[15]','$nubits[16]','$nubits[17]'););


my $retval = $dbh->do($entry);
if($retval < 0){
   print $DBI::errstr;
} else {
   print "entry created successfully\n";
}

my $query = qq(select * from address);
print $query;

$dbh->disconnect();
```

I can manually use sqlite3 from the cli to enter rows, but, as mentioned, I have to manually set the ROWID/Primary ID.

In the past, I've only used sqlite with tcl/tk, never perl, but even though I'm a complete perl n00b, I don't think perl is my problem. sqlite3 is not behaving as expected (unless I've completely misread about a dozen tutorials that state that a primary key id set to autoincrement should, well, autoincrement).

Comment: I've determined that it works like this:
     my $entry = qq(INSERT INTO address ('$dbits[0]','$dbits[1]','$dbits[2]','$dbits[3]','$dbits[4]','$dbits[5]','$dbits[6]','$dbits[7]','$dbits[8]','$dbits[9]','$dbits[10]','$dbits[11]','$dbits[12]','$dbits[13]','$dbits[14]','$dbits[15]','$dbits[16]','$dbits[17]') VALUES('$nubits[0]','$nubits[1]','$nubits[2]','$nubits[3]','$nubits[4]','$nubits[5]','$nubits[6]','$nubits[7]','$nubits[8]','$nubits[9]','$nubits[10]','$nubits[11]','$nubits[12]','$nubits[13]','$nubits[14]','$nubits[15]','$nubits[16]','$nubits[17]'););
it works.

Comment: or my $entry = qq(INSERT INTO address ('LASTNAME','FIRSTNAME','COMPANY','STREET','CITY','STATE','COUNTRY','ZIPCODE','MOBILE','OTHERPHONE','FAX','EMAIL','EMAIL2','WEBSITE','WEBSITE2','DOB','NOTES','TAGS') VALUES('$nubits[0]','$nubits[1]','$nubits[2]','$nubits[3]','$nubits[4]','$nubits[5]','$nubits[6]','$nubits[7]','$nubits[8]','$nubits[9]','$nubits[10]','$nubits[11]','$nubits[12]','$nubits[13]','$nubits[14]','$nubits[15]','$nubits[16]','$nubits[17]'););
of course

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not auto incrementing because you're already giving it an id, `$nubits[0]`.

With no column list, `INSERT INTO address VALUES (...)` inserts all columns in the table.  You [could use `NULL` as @ReenactorRob suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28518923/14660), but that just hides another problem with that query.

`INSERT INTO address VALUES (...)` requires knowledge of the order in which `address` was created to know that element 5 is street.  If anything changes the ordering in the table, your INSERT breaks.  If a column is added, your query breaks.  If you put a value in the wrong slot (as you did) its difficult to tell that.  You're much better off using an explicit column list.

```
INSERT INTO address
    (lastname, firstname, company, street, ...)
VALUES
    (...)
```

Now your ID will increment *and* you're protected from future table changes.  If that seems like a lot of work, make it a function that takes a hash of values to build a query.  It'll be much more readable than remembering what `$nubits[12]` is.  But before you do that, look at [DBIx::Class](http://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class) which has already done this for you.

I would be remiss if I didn't mention [bind parameters](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Placeholders-and-Bind-Values).  These are faster, allowing you to use prepared statements, and they protect you against [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 0):

Try using null in the insert like this:

```
my $entry = qq(INSERT INTO address VALUES(null,'$nubits[0]','$nubits[1]',...
```

Comment: if you are writing the code for work, yes use names and values for documenting/readability.  Quick and dirty, I just use values and null.

Comment: I should think the quality of my perl hackery (or lack thereof) should make it obvious nobody's paying me to do it (yet). Rather, I'm just playing with stuff to try and learn. What I'm doing here in perl/sqlite, I've already done with tcl/sqlite, and with php/mariadb; just now trying to "translate" knowledge from one language to another (what my "real job" is, but that's all Spanish, French, Portuguese and English, not perl, tcl, bash, php, python, etc....the hackery is hobby stuff).

Answer (score 0):

As has been explained, the problem is that the items in the `VALUES` section of the `INSERT` are assigned one-for-one to the table's columns in the order they were first created. If you need to provide values for only a subset of the columns then you also need to provide a list of the column names that should receive the values.

Without the column names the values will be assigned to columns in the order that they were created, so it is the columns at the end that will not receive a value. In this case the database will allocate the value for the `LASTNAME` column to `ID`, and it is the `TAGS` element at the end that doesn't have a value.

It is also much better to use *placeholders* for the values in your SQL statement, and use `prepare` and `execute` instead of just `do`. That way the `DBI` module will quote and escape the actual values appropriately according to their data type.

This program shows how to do that

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;
use DBD::SQLite;

STDOUT->autoflush;

my ($driver, $dbname) = qw/ SQLite myaddress.db /;
my $dsn = "DBI:$driver:dbname=$dbname";

print 'Please enter a DB username: ';
my $username = <STDIN>;
chomp($username);

print 'Please enter a DB password: ';
my $password = <STDIN>;
chomp($password);

my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $username, $password, { RaiseError => 1 });
print "Successful DB connection\n";

print "Creating new address book entry...\n";
print "-----\n";

my @dbits = qw/
  LASTNAME    FIRSTNAME   COMPANY     STREET
  CITY        STATE       COUNTRY     ZIPCODE
  MOBILE      OTHERPHONE  FAX         EMAIL
  EMAIL2      WEBSITE     WEBSITE2    DOB
  NOTES       TAGS
/;

my @nubits;
for my $databit (@dbits) {

  print "Enter $databit: ";
  my $nubit = <STDIN>;
  chomp($nubit);

  push @nubits, $nubit;
  print "$databit = $nubits[-1]\n";
  print scalar @nubits, "\n";
}

my $columns       = join ', ', @dbits;
my $placeholders  = join ', ', ('?') x @dbits;

my $insert = <<"__END__SQL__";
INSERT INTO address (
  $columns
)
VALUES (
  $placeholders
)
__END__SQL__

$insert = $dbh->prepare($insert);
$insert->execute(@nubits);
print "Entry created successfully\n";

$dbh->disconnect;
```

This creates an SQL statement in `$insert` that looks like this

```
INSERT INTO address (
  LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, COMPANY, STREET, CITY, STATE, COUNTRY, ZIPCODE, MOBILE, OTHERPHONE, FAX, EMAIL, EMAIL2, WEBSITE, WEBSITE2, DOB, NOTES, TAGS
)
VALUES (
  ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
)
```